# How to change theme of fancytikzposter

Tags: packages, document-classes, tikz-styles, beamerposter, a0poster

Elena Botoeva has written a new package for creating posters with TikZ. I have already dowloaded the file [*fancytikzposter sources*](http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/tikz/fancytikzposter_sources.zip). I would like to modify  file **fancytikzposter.sty** in order to have another background theme of [julia set](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Julia_set_fractal.png) of the template but unsuccessfully. 
[image: Juliaset]
Here the code

```
>     % fancytikzposter.tex, version 2.1
% Original template created by Elena Botoeva [botoeva@inf.unibz.it], June 2012
%
% This file is distributed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 2.0
% Generic (CC BY-NC 2.0) license
% http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/


\documentclass{a0poster}

\usepackage{fancytikzposter}


%%%%% --------- Change here if you want ---------- %%%%%
%% margin for the geometry package, must be changed before using the geometry package
%% default value is 4cm
% \setmargin{4}

%% the space between the blocks
%% default value is 2cm
% \setblockspacing{2}

%% the height of the title stripe in block nodes, decrease it to save space
%% default value is 3cm
% \setblocktitleheight{3}

%% the number of columns in the poster, possible values 2,3
%% default value is 2
% \setcolumnnumber{3}

%% the space between two or more groups of authors from different institutions
%% used in \maketitle
% \setinstituteshift{10}

%% which template to use
%% N1 simple, standard look, with a colored background and gray boxes
%% N2 board with nodes
%% N3 another standard look
%% N4 envelope-like look
%% N5 with a wave-like head, original idea taken from
%%%% http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/322/1/1/scientific_poster_by_nabuy-d333ria.jpg
%\usetemplate{6}

%% components of the templates
%% (the maximal possible numbers are mentioned as the parameters)
% \usecolortemplate{4}
\renewcommand\BackgroundPicture{%
  \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{juliaset}}
%\renewcommand\backgroundtemplate{}
% \usetitletemplate{2}
% \useblocknodetemplate{5}
% \useplainblocktemplate{4}
% \useinnerblocktemplate{2}


%% the height of the head drawing on top
%% applicable to templates N3, 4 and 5
% \setheaddrawingheight{14}


%% change the basic colors
%\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{008888}
%\setfirstcolor{myblue}% default 116699
%\setsecondcolor{gray!80!}% default CCCCCC
%\setthirdcolor{red!80!black}% default 991111

%% change the more specific colors
% \setbackgrounddarkcolor{colorone!70!black}
% \setbackgroundlightcolor{colorone!70!}
% \settitletextcolor{textcolor}
% \settitlefillcolor{white}
% \settitledrawcolor{colortwo}
% \setblocktextcolor{textcolor}
% \setblockfillcolor{white}
% \setblocktitletextcolor{colorone}
% \setblocktitlefillcolor{colortwo} %the color of the border
% \setplainblocktextcolor{textcolor}
% \setplainblockfillcolor{colorthree!40!}
% \setplainblocktitletextcolor{textcolor}
% \setplainblocktitlefillcolor{colorthree!60!}
% \setinnerblocktextcolor{textcolor}
% \setinnerblockfillcolor{white}
% \setinnerblocktitletextcolor{white}
% \setinnerblocktitlefillcolor{colorthree}




%%% size of the document and the margins
%% A0
% \usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=118.9cm, paperheight=84.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=118.9cm]{geometry}
%% B1
% \usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=70cm, paperheight=100cm]{geometry}



%% changing the fonts
\usepackage{cmbright}
%\usepackage[default]{cantarell}
%\usepackage{avant}
%\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


%% add your packages here
\usepackage{hyperref}





\title{Scientific Poster with TikZ \qquad version 2.1}
\author{Elena Botoeva\\
  KRDB Research Centre, Free University of Bozen-Bolzano, Italy\\
  \texttt{botoeva@inf.unibz.it}
}


\begin{document}

%%%%% ---------- the background picture ---------- %%%%%
%% to change it modify the macro \BackgroundPicture
\ClearShipoutPicture
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicture}

\noindent % to have the picture right in the center
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \initializesizeandshifts
  % \setxshift{15}
  % \setyshift{2}


  %% the title block, #1 - shift, the default value is (0,0), #2 - width, #3 - scale
  %% the alias of the title block is `title', so we can refer to its boundaries later
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\template}{1}}{
    \titleblock{47}{1}
  }{
    \titleblock{47}{1.5}
  }

  %% a logo can be added to the title block
  %% #1 - anchor relative to the title block, #2 - shift, #3 - width, #3 - file name
  % \ifthenelse{\equal{\template}{2}}{
  %   \addlogo[south west]{(2,0)}{6cm}{unibz_b.png}
  % }{
  %   \addlogo[south west]{(2,0)}{6cm}{unibz_w.png}
  % }


  %% a block node, with the specified position (optional), title and the content
  %% #1 - where (optional), #2 - title, #3 - text
  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknode%
  {Starting}%
  {Start with the following document:

    \coloredbox{colorthree!50!}{
      \textbackslash documentclass\{a0poster\}\\
      \textbackslash usepackage\{fancytikzposter\} \% here most of the things are
      defined \\

      \% change parameters only after this line\\

      \textbackslash usepackage{\small[margin=\textbackslash margin \ cm,
        paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=118.9cm]\{ geometry\}} \\

      \textbackslash title\{Title\}\\
      \textbackslash author\{Author\textbackslash\textbackslash
      Institution\textbackslash\textbackslash
      \textbackslash texttt\{email\}\}\\
      \textbackslash begin\{document\}\\
      \textbackslash AddToShipoutPicture\{\textbackslash BackgroundPicture\}\\


      \textbackslash noindent \\
      \textbackslash begin\{tikzpicture\} \\
      \textbackslash initializesizeandshifts \\

      \textbackslash titleblock\{50\}\{1\}\\
      \textbackslash blocknode\{Block Title\}\{Block Content\}\\
      \textbackslash startsecondcolumn\\
      \textbackslash blocknode\{Block Title 2\}\{Block Content 2\}\\
      \textbackslash end\{tikzpicture\}\\
      \textbackslash end\{document\}
    }
  }


  %% a callout block
  %% #1 - rotate angle (optional), #2 - from, #3 - where, #4 - width, #5 - text
  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \calloutblock{($(box.center)+(-2,-8)$)}
  {($(box.center)+(10,-1)$)}
  {19cm}
  {\small
    Macro for creating a block node:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash blocknode\{Block Title\}\{Block Content\}
    \end{itemize}
    Macro \textbackslash blocknode has three parameters. The first one is
    optional and it is the position of the block. The first block will be
    automatically placed to (\$(firstrow)-(xshift)-(yshift)\$), which is the
    left corner below the title block. In most of the templates, (firstrow) is
    set to (title.south), where \emph{title} is the alias for the title
    block. Each subsequent block is automatically placed to
    [(\$(box.south)-(yshift)\$)], i.e., below the previous block aliased
    \emph{box}.  You can also use an explicit parameter, e.g., $(-10,30)$ (note
    that (0,0) is the center of the poster). The second parameter is the title
    of the block. Finally, the last parameter is the  actual content.
  }




  %% by default, the position of the new block node is right below the previous
  %% block node, stored in (currenty)
  %% box is the alias of the previous block, so we can refer to its boundaries

  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknode{Making Title}%
  {To make title, use the standard commands \textbackslash title and
    \textbackslash author in the preamble, and then the following macro:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash titleblock\{50\}\{1.5\}
    \end{itemize}
    Macro \textbackslash titleblock has three parameters. The first one is
    optional and it specifies the shift of the title block w.r.t.\ its default
    position, which is set to (\$0.5*(0,\textbackslash
    paperheight)-(0,\textbackslash margin)\$). The second parameter is the width
    of the title block, and the third parameter is the scaling ratio (to make
    the title bigger or smaller).\\

    \small
    The syntax for specifying authors is similar to the one in aaai.sty.  Author
    information can be set in various styles: For several authors from the same
    institution:
    \begin{itemize}\item[]
      \textbackslash author\{Author 1 \textbackslash and ... \textbackslash and
      Author n \textbackslash\textbackslash\\
      Address line \textbackslash\textbackslash \
      ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address line\}
    \end{itemize}

    If the names do not fit well on one line use
    \begin{itemize}\item[]
      \textbackslash author\{Author 1 \textbackslash\textbackslash \
      \{\textbackslash bf Author 2\} \textbackslash\textbackslash \
      ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \
      \{\textbackslash bf Author n\} \textbackslash\textbackslash\\
      Address line \textbackslash\textbackslash \
      ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address line\}
    \end{itemize}

    For authors from different institutions:
    \begin{itemize}\item[]
      \textbackslash author\{Author 1 \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address
      line \textbackslash\textbackslash \ ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \
      Address line \\ \textbackslash And ... \textbackslash And \\
      Author n \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address line
      \textbackslash\textbackslash \ ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address
      line\}
    \end{itemize}

    To start a separate ``row'' of authors use \textbackslash AND, as in
    \begin{itemize}\item[]
      \textbackslash author\{Author 1 \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address line
      \textbackslash\textbackslash \ ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address
      line \textbackslash AND\\ Author 2 \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address line
      \textbackslash\textbackslash \ ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address
      line \textbackslash And\\ Author 3 \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address line
      \textbackslash\textbackslash \ ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address
      line\}
    \end{itemize}
    (though, I must say \textbackslash and ... \textbackslash and did not work for
    me with more than 2 authors, so just use commas where you need if it does
    not work for you either).
  }


  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknodew[($(currenty)-(3.5,0)$)]{30}{Variable Width Block Nodes} %
  { You can also create blocks of arbitrary width
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash blocknodew[coordinate]\{Block width\}\{Block Title\}%
      \{Block Content\}
    \end{itemize}
    %
    In this case it is better to specify coordinate manually if you want to have
    blocks aligned vertically. \\

    Note that (xshift) and (yshift) are coordinates created in macro
    \textbackslash initializesizeandshifts, and they allow to have relative
    positioning of block nodes in an automatic fashion. If you want to define
    your own shifts, set new values for (xshift) and (yshift) using commands
    \textbackslash setxshift and \textbackslash setyshift.\\

    Also, it might be useful to know the y-coordinate of the south border of the
    previous block. You can retrieve it by using the command
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash getcurrentrow\{box\} or \textbackslash getcurrentrow\{note\}
    \end{itemize}
    This coordinate will be stored in (currentrow), which can be used to
    specify the location of the next block node.
  }


  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \plainblock[5]{($(currenty)+(4,2)$)}{35}{fancyTikZposter template} %
  {

    \vspace{0.3cm}
    It is a template for scientific posters based on a0poster and TikZ
    only. The current version contains five (plus one) different templates (see my
    posters
    %
    \href{http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/presentations/abcrs-KR-12-poster.pdf}{%
      \underline{here}} and
    %
    \href{http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/presentations/boto-RR-12-poster.pdf}{%
      \underline{here}}). The sources of this pdf file can be found
    \href{http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/tikz/tikzposter_sources.zip}{\underline{here}}.}




  %%%%%%%%%%%%% NEW COLUMN %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \startsecondcolumn

  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknode%
  {Block Nodes in the Second Column}%
  {To start the second column or the third column use commands
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash startsecondcolumn, and \textbackslash startthirdcolumn.
    \end{itemize}
    If the number of columns is 2, then the last command will not have
    effect. \\

    You can also start a new column with an arbitrary x-coordinate by specifying
    explicitly the coordinate of the new block node as follows:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash blocknode[(\$(firstrow)-(yshift)+(x,0)\$)]\{Block
      Title\}\{Block Content\}
    \end{itemize}

    %
  }



  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknode{Useful Macro Within Block Nodes}%
  {There are three types of colored boxes/blocks that you can use inside block
    nodes to highlight information. \\

    \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
      \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \innerblock{Theorem} {Statement}
      \end{minipage}
      &
      \textbackslash innerblock\{Theorem\}\{Statement\}\\

      \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \innerblockplain[colorone!80!]{Text}
      \end{minipage}
      &
      \textbackslash innerblockplain[colorone!80!]\{Text\}\\

      \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \coloredbox{colorthree!50!}{Text}
      \end{minipage}
      &
      \textbackslash coloredbox\{colorthree!50!\}\{Text\}
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{0.5cm}
    The default figure environment does not work within a tikzpicture. I created
    a new figure environment that can be used instead, based on the code sent by
    Stephan Thober.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash begin\{tikzfigure\}[Caption]\\
      \ldots\\
      \textbackslash end\{tikzfigure\}
    \end{itemize}
    %

    \begin{tikzfigure}[A shaded circle]
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[draw=none,inner color=colorthree, outer color=colorone] (0,0) circle (2cm);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tikzfigure}
  }


  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \calloutblock{($(box.south east)-(8,-2)$)}
  {($(box.south east)-(16,2)$)}
  {30cm}
  {
    There are also callout blocks that allow for a more interesting layout of the
    poster.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash calloutblock[rotate angle]\{from
      coordinate\}\{coordinate\}\{Block Width\}\{Block Content\}
    \end{itemize}
    The alias for such blocks is \emph{note}.
  }


  %% to place the next node centered vertically in the second column, we can
  %% obtain the y-coordinate of the previous node using macro
  %% \getcurrentrow{note}, where note is the alias of the callout node, and
  %% then specify the coordinate of the next node using coordinate (currentrow)
  \getcurrentrow{note}


  %% a plain block
  %% #1 - rotate angle (optional), #2 - where, #3 - width, #4 - title, #5 - text
  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \plainblock{($(currentrow)+(xshift)-(yshift)$)}%[($(currenty)+(0,10)$)]%
  {32}{Plain blocks} %
  {These blocks are similar to callout blocks. They allow for specifying the
    title of the block.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash plainblock[rotate angle]\{coordinate\}\{Block Width\}\{Block
      Title\}\{Block Content\}
    \end{itemize}
  }



  %% the coordinate (currenty) is used in the default placing of the next blocknode
 \getcurrentrow{note}
 \coordinate (currenty) at ($(currentrow)+(xshift)-(yshift)$);



   %%%%%%%%%%%%% NEW COLUMN %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %% (if column number is 3)
  \startthirdcolumn

  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknode {Personalizing the Poster}%
  {It is possible to adjust the layout of the poster. To impose your own
    setting, you can use these macros:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Macros for changing sizes
      \begin{itemize}
      \item[] \textbackslash setmargin\{4\},
        %% the height of the head drawing on top
        %% applicable to templates N2 and 4
        \textbackslash setheaddrawingheight\{14\},
        %% the space between two or more groups of authors from different
        %% institutions
        %% used in \maketitle
        \textbackslash setinstituteshift\{10\},\\
        %% the space between the blocks
        %% default value is 2cm
        \textbackslash setblockspacing\{2\},
        %% the height of the title stripe in block nodes, decrease it to save space
        %% default value is 3cm
        \textbackslash setblocktitleheight\{3\}
      \end{itemize}

    \item Other structural macros
      \begin{itemize}
      \item[]  %% the number of columns in the poster, possible values 2,3
        %% default value is 2
        \textbackslash setcolumnnumber\{3\},
        %% which template to use
        %% N1 simple, standard look, with a colored background and gray boxes
        %% N2 board with nodes
        %% N3 another standard look
        %% N4 envelope like look
        %% N5 with a wave-like head, original idea taken from
        %%%% http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/322/1/1/scientific_poster_by_nabuy-d333ria.jpg
        %% N6 experimental, oriental style, largely based on template N3
        \textbackslash usetemplate\{6\},\\
        \textbackslash usecolortemplate\{4\},
        \textbackslash usebackgroundtemplate\{5\},
        \textbackslash usetitletemplate\{2\},\\
        \textbackslash useblocknodetemplate\{5\},
        \textbackslash useinnerblocktemplate\{3\},
        \textbackslash useplainblocktemplate\{4\}

      \end{itemize}

    \item Macro for adding logos to the title block
      \begin{itemize}
      \item[] \textbackslash addlogo[south west]\{(0,0)\}\{6cm\}\{filename\}
      \end{itemize}

    \item Macros for the basic colors
      \begin{itemize}
      \item[] \textbackslash setfirstcolor\{green!70!\}, % default 116699
        \textbackslash setsecondcolor\{gray!80!\}, % default CCCCCC
        \textbackslash setthirdcolor\{red!80!black\}% default 991111
      \end{itemize}

    \item Macros for specific colors:
      \begin{itemize}
      \item[] \textbackslash setbackgrounddarkcolor\{colorone!70!black\},
        \textbackslash setbackgroundlightcolor\{{\small colorone!70!}\},\\
        \textbackslash settitletextcolor\{textcolor\},
        \textbackslash settitlefillcolor\{white\},
        \textbackslash settitledrawcolor\{colortwo\},\\
        \textbackslash setblocktextcolor\{textcolor\},
        \textbackslash setblockfillcolor\{white\},\\
        \textbackslash setblocktitletextcolor\{colorone\},
        \textbackslash setblocktitlefillcolor\{colortwo\}, \\
        \textbackslash setplainblocktextcolor\{textcolor\},
        \textbackslash setplainblockfillcolor\{colorthree!40\},\\
        \textbackslash setplainblocktitletextcolor\{textcolor\},
        \textbackslash setplainblocktitlefillcolor\{colorthree!60\}, \\
        \textbackslash setinnerblocktextcolor\{textcolor\},
        \textbackslash setinnerblockfillcolor\{white\},\\
        \textbackslash setinnerblocktitletextcolor\{white\},
        \textbackslash setinnerblocktitlefillcolor\{colorthree\},
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  }



\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I got this [image: fancytikzposter]

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question, Do you already have the code for the Julia set and want to know how to include it as the default background?

Comment: I will write the ecode for the julia set.

Comment: Will the code be written in TikZ, MetaPost or similars? In any case, you can produce the image, save it as an image file and then include it in the background as in my example, or I am misunderstanding what you want to achieve?

Comment: that is what I have done Sir

Comment: And did you get the desired result or are you experiencing any problems? If so, please upload the `juliaset` image elsewhere and provide a link so I can do some tests.

Comment: no I hav'nt the desred image. The link  is in my question

Comment: @Zbigniew try `\includegraphics[scale=5.5]{juliaset}}`

Comment: @Zbigniew Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Zbigniew Ah, but now that I re-read you question, you are interested in modifying the .sty file so you can access the `juliaset` background as any other of the predefined styles?

Comment: @Zbigniew please see my updated answer which now includes a modification of the `.sty` file to define a new `julia` background style.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine `\BackGroundPicture` to use any image you like:

```
\renewcommand\BackgroundPicture{%
  \includegraphics[<options>]{<image file>}}
```

A little example in which I used

```
\renewcommand\BackgroundPicture{%
  \includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{juliaset}}
```

for the image provided in the link (I used the [`1024px`](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Julia_set_fractal.png/1024px-Julia_set_fractal.png) version and saved it as `juliaset.png`):

```
% fancytikzposter.tex, version 2.1
% Original template created by Elena Botoeva [botoeva@inf.unibz.it], June 2012
% 
% This file is distributed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 2.0
% Generic (CC BY-NC 2.0) license
% http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/ 


\documentclass{a0poster}

\usepackage{fancytikzposter} 


%%%%% --------- Change here if you want ---------- %%%%%
%% margin for the geometry package, must be changed before using the geometry package
%% default value is 4cm
% \setmargin{4}

%% the space between the blocks
%% default value is 2cm
% \setblockspacing{2}

%% the height of the title stripe in block nodes, decrease it to save space
%% default value is 3cm
% \setblocktitleheight{3}

%% the number of columns in the poster, possible values 2,3
%% default value is 2
% \setcolumnnumber{3}

%% the space between two or more groups of authors from different institutions
%% used in \maketitle
% \setinstituteshift{10}

%% which template to use
%% N1 simple, standard look, with a colored background and gray boxes
%% N2 board with nodes
%% N3 another standard look
%% N4 envelope-like look
%% N5 with a wave-like head, original idea taken from
%%%% http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/322/1/1/scientific_poster_by_nabuy-d333ria.jpg
%\usetemplate{6}

%% components of the templates
%% (the maximal possible numbers are mentioned as the parameters)
% \usecolortemplate{4}
\renewcommand\BackgroundPicture{%
  \includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{juliaset}}
%\renewcommand\backgroundtemplate{}
% \usetitletemplate{2}
% \useblocknodetemplate{5}
% \useplainblocktemplate{4}
% \useinnerblocktemplate{2}


%% the height of the head drawing on top 
%% applicable to templates N3, 4 and 5
% \setheaddrawingheight{14}


%% change the basic colors
%\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{008888} 
%\setfirstcolor{myblue}% default 116699
%\setsecondcolor{gray!80!}% default CCCCCC
%\setthirdcolor{red!80!black}% default 991111

%% change the more specific colors
% \setbackgrounddarkcolor{colorone!70!black}
% \setbackgroundlightcolor{colorone!70!}
% \settitletextcolor{textcolor}
% \settitlefillcolor{white}
% \settitledrawcolor{colortwo}
% \setblocktextcolor{textcolor}
% \setblockfillcolor{white}
% \setblocktitletextcolor{colorone}
% \setblocktitlefillcolor{colortwo} %the color of the border
% \setplainblocktextcolor{textcolor}
% \setplainblockfillcolor{colorthree!40!}
% \setplainblocktitletextcolor{textcolor}
% \setplainblocktitlefillcolor{colorthree!60!}
% \setinnerblocktextcolor{textcolor}
% \setinnerblockfillcolor{white}
% \setinnerblocktitletextcolor{white}
% \setinnerblocktitlefillcolor{colorthree}




%%% size of the document and the margins
%% A0
% \usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=118.9cm, paperheight=84.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=118.9cm]{geometry}
%% B1
% \usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=70cm, paperheight=100cm]{geometry}



%% changing the fonts
\usepackage{cmbright}
%\usepackage[default]{cantarell}
%\usepackage{avant}
%\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


%% add your packages here
\usepackage{hyperref}





\title{Scientific Poster with TikZ \qquad version 2.1}
\author{Elena Botoeva\\
  KRDB Research Centre, Free University of Bozen-Bolzano, Italy\\
  \texttt{botoeva@inf.unibz.it}
}


\begin{document}

%%%%% ---------- the background picture ---------- %%%%%
%% to change it modify the macro \BackgroundPicture
\ClearShipoutPicture
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicture}

\noindent % to have the picture right in the center
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \initializesizeandshifts
  % \setxshift{15}
  % \setyshift{2}


  %% the title block, #1 - shift, the default value is (0,0), #2 - width, #3 - scale
  %% the alias of the title block is `title', so we can refer to its boundaries later
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\template}{1}}{ 
    \titleblock{47}{1}
  }{
    \titleblock{47}{1.5}
  }

  %% a logo can be added to the title block
  %% #1 - anchor relative to the title block, #2 - shift, #3 - width, #3 - file name
  % \ifthenelse{\equal{\template}{2}}{ 
  %   \addlogo[south west]{(2,0)}{6cm}{unibz_b.png}
  % }{
  %   \addlogo[south west]{(2,0)}{6cm}{unibz_w.png}
  % }


  %% a block node, with the specified position (optional), title and the content
  %% #1 - where (optional), #2 - title, #3 - text
  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknode%
  {Starting}%
  {Start with the following document:

    \coloredbox{colorthree!50!}{
      \textbackslash documentclass\{a0poster\}\\
      \textbackslash usepackage\{fancytikzposter\} \% here most of the things are
      defined \\

      \% change parameters only after this line\\

      \textbackslash usepackage{\small[margin=\textbackslash margin \ cm,
        paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=118.9cm]\{ geometry\}} \\

      \textbackslash title\{Title\}\\
      \textbackslash author\{Author\textbackslash\textbackslash
      Institution\textbackslash\textbackslash
      \textbackslash texttt\{email\}\}\\
      \textbackslash begin\{document\}\\
      \textbackslash AddToShipoutPicture\{\textbackslash BackgroundPicture\}\\


      \textbackslash noindent \\
      \textbackslash begin\{tikzpicture\} \\
      \textbackslash initializesizeandshifts \\

      \textbackslash titleblock\{50\}\{1\}\\
      \textbackslash blocknode\{Block Title\}\{Block Content\}\\
      \textbackslash startsecondcolumn\\
      \textbackslash blocknode\{Block Title 2\}\{Block Content 2\}\\
      \textbackslash end\{tikzpicture\}\\
      \textbackslash end\{document\}
    }
  }


  %% a callout block
  %% #1 - rotate angle (optional), #2 - from, #3 - where, #4 - width, #5 - text
  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \calloutblock{($(box.center)+(-2,-8)$)}
  {($(box.center)+(10,-1)$)}
  {19cm}
  {\small
    Macro for creating a block node:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash blocknode\{Block Title\}\{Block Content\}
    \end{itemize}
    Macro \textbackslash blocknode has three parameters. The first one is
    optional and it is the position of the block. The first block will be
    automatically placed to (\$(firstrow)-(xshift)-(yshift)\$), which is the
    left corner below the title block. In most of the templates, (firstrow) is
    set to (title.south), where \emph{title} is the alias for the title
    block. Each subsequent block is automatically placed to
    [(\$(box.south)-(yshift)\$)], i.e., below the previous block aliased
    \emph{box}.  You can also use an explicit parameter, e.g., $(-10,30)$ (note
    that (0,0) is the center of the poster). The second parameter is the title
    of the block. Finally, the last parameter is the  actual content. 
  }




  %% by default, the position of the new block node is right below the previous
  %% block node, stored in (currenty)
  %% box is the alias of the previous block, so we can refer to its boundaries

  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknode{Making Title}%
  {To make title, use the standard commands \textbackslash title and
    \textbackslash author in the preamble, and then the following macro:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash titleblock\{50\}\{1.5\}
    \end{itemize}
    Macro \textbackslash titleblock has three parameters. The first one is
    optional and it specifies the shift of the title block w.r.t.\ its default
    position, which is set to (\$0.5*(0,\textbackslash
    paperheight)-(0,\textbackslash margin)\$). The second parameter is the width
    of the title block, and the third parameter is the scaling ratio (to make
    the title bigger or smaller).\\

    \small
    The syntax for specifying authors is similar to the one in aaai.sty.  Author
    information can be set in various styles: For several authors from the same
    institution:
    \begin{itemize}\item[] 
      \textbackslash author\{Author 1 \textbackslash and ... \textbackslash and
      Author n \textbackslash\textbackslash\\ 
      Address line \textbackslash\textbackslash \
      ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address line\}
    \end{itemize}

    If the names do not fit well on one line use
    \begin{itemize}\item[] 
      \textbackslash author\{Author 1 \textbackslash\textbackslash \
      \{\textbackslash bf Author 2\} \textbackslash\textbackslash \
      ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \
      \{\textbackslash bf Author n\} \textbackslash\textbackslash\\
      Address line \textbackslash\textbackslash \
      ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address line\}
    \end{itemize}

    For authors from different institutions: 
    \begin{itemize}\item[] 
      \textbackslash author\{Author 1 \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address
      line \textbackslash\textbackslash \ ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \
      Address line \\ \textbackslash And ... \textbackslash And \\
      Author n \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address line
      \textbackslash\textbackslash \ ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address
      line\}
    \end{itemize}

    To start a separate ``row'' of authors use \textbackslash AND, as in
    \begin{itemize}\item[] 
      \textbackslash author\{Author 1 \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address line
      \textbackslash\textbackslash \ ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address
      line \textbackslash AND\\ Author 2 \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address line
      \textbackslash\textbackslash \ ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address
      line \textbackslash And\\ Author 3 \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address line
      \textbackslash\textbackslash \ ... \textbackslash\textbackslash \ Address
      line\}
    \end{itemize}
    (though, I must say \textbackslash and ... \textbackslash and did not work for
    me with more than 2 authors, so just use commas where you need if it does
    not work for you either).
  }


  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknodew[($(currenty)-(3.5,0)$)]{30}{Variable Width Block Nodes} %
  { You can also create blocks of arbitrary width
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash blocknodew[coordinate]\{Block width\}\{Block Title\}%
      \{Block Content\}
    \end{itemize} 
    % 
    In this case it is better to specify coordinate manually if you want to have
    blocks aligned vertically. \\

    Note that (xshift) and (yshift) are coordinates created in macro
    \textbackslash initializesizeandshifts, and they allow to have relative
    positioning of block nodes in an automatic fashion. If you want to define
    your own shifts, set new values for (xshift) and (yshift) using commands
    \textbackslash setxshift and \textbackslash setyshift.\\

    Also, it might be useful to know the y-coordinate of the south border of the
    previous block. You can retrieve it by using the command
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash getcurrentrow\{box\} or \textbackslash getcurrentrow\{note\}
    \end{itemize}
    This coordinate will be stored in (currentrow), which can be used to
    specify the location of the next block node.
  }


  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \plainblock[5]{($(currenty)+(4,2)$)}{35}{fancyTikZposter template} %
  {

    \vspace{0.3cm}
    It is a template for scientific posters based on a0poster and TikZ
    only. The current version contains five (plus one) different templates (see my
    posters
    % 
    \href{http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/presentations/abcrs-KR-12-poster.pdf}{%
      \underline{here}} and
    % 
    \href{http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/presentations/boto-RR-12-poster.pdf}{%
      \underline{here}}). The sources of this pdf file can be found
    \href{http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/tikz/tikzposter_sources.zip}{\underline{here}}.}




  %%%%%%%%%%%%% NEW COLUMN %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
  \startsecondcolumn 

  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknode%
  {Block Nodes in the Second Column}%
  {To start the second column or the third column use commands
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash startsecondcolumn, and \textbackslash startthirdcolumn.
    \end{itemize}
    If the number of columns is 2, then the last command will not have
    effect. \\

    You can also start a new column with an arbitrary x-coordinate by specifying
    explicitly the coordinate of the new block node as follows:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash blocknode[(\$(firstrow)-(yshift)+(x,0)\$)]\{Block
      Title\}\{Block Content\}
    \end{itemize}

    % 
  }



  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknode{Useful Macro Within Block Nodes}%
  {There are three types of colored boxes/blocks that you can use inside block
    nodes to highlight information. \\

    \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
      \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \innerblock{Theorem} {Statement}
      \end{minipage}
      & 
      \textbackslash innerblock\{Theorem\}\{Statement\}\\

      \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \innerblockplain[colorone!80!]{Text}
      \end{minipage}
      &
      \textbackslash innerblockplain[colorone!80!]\{Text\}\\ 

      \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \coloredbox{colorthree!50!}{Text}
      \end{minipage}
      &
      \textbackslash coloredbox\{colorthree!50!\}\{Text\}
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{0.5cm}
    The default figure environment does not work within a tikzpicture. I created
    a new figure environment that can be used instead, based on the code sent by
    Stephan Thober.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash begin\{tikzfigure\}[Caption]\\
      \ldots\\
      \textbackslash end\{tikzfigure\}
    \end{itemize} 
    % 

    \begin{tikzfigure}[A shaded circle]
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[draw=none,inner color=colorthree, outer color=colorone] (0,0) circle (2cm);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tikzfigure}
  }


  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \calloutblock{($(box.south east)-(8,-2)$)}
  {($(box.south east)-(16,2)$)}
  {30cm}
  {
    There are also callout blocks that allow for a more interesting layout of the
    poster. 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash calloutblock[rotate angle]\{from
      coordinate\}\{coordinate\}\{Block Width\}\{Block Content\} 
    \end{itemize}
    The alias for such blocks is \emph{note}.
  }


  %% to place the next node centered vertically in the second column, we can
  %% obtain the y-coordinate of the previous node using macro
  %% \getcurrentrow{note}, where note is the alias of the callout node, and
  %% then specify the coordinate of the next node using coordinate (currentrow)
  \getcurrentrow{note}


  %% a plain block
  %% #1 - rotate angle (optional), #2 - where, #3 - width, #4 - title, #5 - text
  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \plainblock{($(currentrow)+(xshift)-(yshift)$)}%[($(currenty)+(0,10)$)]%
  {32}{Plain blocks} %
  {These blocks are similar to callout blocks. They allow for specifying the
    title of the block.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash plainblock[rotate angle]\{coordinate\}\{Block Width\}\{Block
      Title\}\{Block Content\} 
    \end{itemize}
  }



  %% the coordinate (currenty) is used in the default placing of the next blocknode
 \getcurrentrow{note}
 \coordinate (currenty) at ($(currentrow)+(xshift)-(yshift)$);



   %%%%%%%%%%%%% NEW COLUMN %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
  %% (if column number is 3)
  \startthirdcolumn

  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknode {Personalizing the Poster}%
  {It is possible to adjust the layout of the poster. To impose your own
    setting, you can use these macros:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Macros for changing sizes
      \begin{itemize}
      \item[] \textbackslash setmargin\{4\},
        %% the height of the head drawing on top
        %% applicable to templates N2 and 4
        \textbackslash setheaddrawingheight\{14\},
        %% the space between two or more groups of authors from different
        %% institutions
        %% used in \maketitle
        \textbackslash setinstituteshift\{10\},\\
        %% the space between the blocks
        %% default value is 2cm
        \textbackslash setblockspacing\{2\},
        %% the height of the title stripe in block nodes, decrease it to save space
        %% default value is 3cm
        \textbackslash setblocktitleheight\{3\}
      \end{itemize}

    \item Other structural macros
      \begin{itemize}
      \item[]  %% the number of columns in the poster, possible values 2,3
        %% default value is 2
        \textbackslash setcolumnnumber\{3\},
        %% which template to use 
        %% N1 simple, standard look, with a colored background and gray boxes
        %% N2 board with nodes
        %% N3 another standard look
        %% N4 envelope like look
        %% N5 with a wave-like head, original idea taken from
        %%%% http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/322/1/1/scientific_poster_by_nabuy-d333ria.jpg
        %% N6 experimental, oriental style, largely based on template N3
        \textbackslash usetemplate\{6\},\\
        \textbackslash usecolortemplate\{4\},
        \textbackslash usebackgroundtemplate\{5\},
        \textbackslash usetitletemplate\{2\},\\
        \textbackslash useblocknodetemplate\{5\},
        \textbackslash useinnerblocktemplate\{3\},
        \textbackslash useplainblocktemplate\{4\}

      \end{itemize}

    \item Macro for adding logos to the title block
      \begin{itemize}
      \item[] \textbackslash addlogo[south west]\{(0,0)\}\{6cm\}\{filename\}
      \end{itemize}

    \item Macros for the basic colors
      \begin{itemize}
      \item[] \textbackslash setfirstcolor\{green!70!\}, % default 116699
        \textbackslash setsecondcolor\{gray!80!\}, % default CCCCCC
        \textbackslash setthirdcolor\{red!80!black\}% default 991111
      \end{itemize}

    \item Macros for specific colors:
      \begin{itemize}
      \item[] \textbackslash setbackgrounddarkcolor\{colorone!70!black\},
        \textbackslash setbackgroundlightcolor\{{\small colorone!70!}\},\\
        \textbackslash settitletextcolor\{textcolor\},
        \textbackslash settitlefillcolor\{white\},
        \textbackslash settitledrawcolor\{colortwo\},\\
        \textbackslash setblocktextcolor\{textcolor\},
        \textbackslash setblockfillcolor\{white\},\\
        \textbackslash setblocktitletextcolor\{colorone\},
        \textbackslash setblocktitlefillcolor\{colortwo\}, \\
        \textbackslash setplainblocktextcolor\{textcolor\},
        \textbackslash setplainblockfillcolor\{colorthree!40\},\\
        \textbackslash setplainblocktitletextcolor\{textcolor\},
        \textbackslash setplainblocktitlefillcolor\{colorthree!60\}, \\
        \textbackslash setinnerblocktextcolor\{textcolor\},
        \textbackslash setinnerblockfillcolor\{white\},\\
        \textbackslash setinnerblocktitletextcolor\{white\},
        \textbackslash setinnerblocktitlefillcolor\{colorthree\},
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  }



\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

If what you want is to modify the original `.sty` file to have a new background style, then you need to change the definition of `\BackgroundPicture` (in `fancytikzposter.sty`). The following code shows how to do this redefinition to add a new background template called `julia`; the new lines are around line 565 and are marked with `%NEW`. The resulting file is too big to paste it here directly, but I've uploaded it to pastebin [`following this link`](http://pastebin.com/gaAtTNbj).

With the modified .sty file, you simply use

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{julia}
```

to have the `juliaset` image as background; a little example:

```
\documentclass{a0poster}

\usepackage{fancytikzposter} 

\usebackgroundtemplate{julia}
\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=118.9cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Scientific Poster with TikZ \qquad version 2.1}
\author{Elena Botoeva\\
  KRDB Research Centre, Free University of Bozen-Bolzano, Italy\\
  \texttt{botoeva@inf.unibz.it}
}


\begin{document}

\ClearShipoutPicture
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicture}

\noindent % to have the picture right in the center
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \initializesizeandshifts

  \ifthenelse{\equal{\template}{1}}{ 
    \titleblock{47}{1}
  }{
    \titleblock{47}{1.5}
  }

  %% a logo can be added to the title block
  %% #1 - anchor relative to the title block, #2 - shift, #3 - width, #3 - file name
  % \ifthenelse{\equal{\template}{2}}{ 
  %   \addlogo[south west]{(2,0)}{6cm}{unibz_b.png}
  % }{
  %   \addlogo[south west]{(2,0)}{6cm}{unibz_w.png}
  % }


  %% a block node, with the specified position (optional), title and the content
  %% #1 - where (optional), #2 - title, #3 - text
  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \blocknode%
  {Starting}%
  {Start with the following document:

    \coloredbox{colorthree!50!}{
      \textbackslash documentclass\{a0poster\}\\
      \textbackslash usepackage\{fancytikzposter\} \% here most of the things are
      defined \\

      \% change parameters only after this line\\

      \textbackslash usepackage{\small[margin=\textbackslash margin \ cm,
        paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=118.9cm]\{ geometry\}} \\

      \textbackslash title\{Title\}\\
      \textbackslash author\{Author\textbackslash\textbackslash
      Institution\textbackslash\textbackslash
      \textbackslash texttt\{email\}\}\\
      \textbackslash begin\{document\}\\
      \textbackslash AddToShipoutPicture\{\textbackslash BackgroundPicture\}\\


      \textbackslash noindent \\
      \textbackslash begin\{tikzpicture\} \\
      \textbackslash initializesizeandshifts \\

      \textbackslash titleblock\{50\}\{1\}\\
      \textbackslash blocknode\{Block Title\}\{Block Content\}\\
      \textbackslash startsecondcolumn\\
      \textbackslash blocknode\{Block Title 2\}\{Block Content 2\}\\
      \textbackslash end\{tikzpicture\}\\
      \textbackslash end\{document\}
    }
  }


  %% a callout block
  %% #1 - rotate angle (optional), #2 - from, #3 - where, #4 - width, #5 - text
  %%%%%%%%%% ------------------------------------------ %%%%%%%%%%
  \calloutblock{($(box.center)+(-2,-8)$)}
  {($(box.center)+(10,-1)$)}
  {19cm}
  {\small
    Macro for creating a block node:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbackslash blocknode\{Block Title\}\{Block Content\}
    \end{itemize}
    Macro \textbackslash blocknode has three parameters. The first one is
    optional and it is the position of the block. The first block will be
    automatically placed to (\$(firstrow)-(xshift)-(yshift)\$), which is the
    left corner below the title block. In most of the templates, (firstrow) is
    set to (title.south), where \emph{title} is the alias for the title
    block. Each subsequent block is automatically placed to
    [(\$(box.south)-(yshift)\$)], i.e., below the previous block aliased
    \emph{box}.  You can also use an explicit parameter, e.g., $(-10,30)$ (note
    that (0,0) is the center of the poster). The second parameter is the title
    of the block. Finally, the last parameter is the  actual content. 
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

Of course, the better the quality of the image used, the better.

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply. I have compile the script. I have a gruesome picture. I wonder how you could have this beautiful  background theme. So i will imrove the question.